# Settings API in Section

Tags: settings-api

I have a snippet that creates an option in Settings->General using Settings API. However, the values don't get updated and I was wondering if anyone can help point out the problem with the following code

```
function admin_init_callback() {

    register_setting( 'msp_settings', 'msp_duration' );

    add_settings_section( 'msp_settings', __('Multisite Posts Configuration'), false, 'general' );

    add_settings_field( 'msp_duration', __('Cache Duration'), array($this, 'msp_settings_callback'), 'general', 'msp_settings', array(
        "id"    => "msp_duration",
        "type"  => "dropdown",
        "values"=> array(
            array(
                "name"  => __('Every 6 hours'),
                "value" => 60 * 60 * 6,
            ),
            array(
                "name"  => __('Every 12 hours'),
                "value" => 60 * 60 * 12,
            ),
            array(
                "name"  => __('Every 24 hours'),
                "value" => 60 * 60 * 24,
            ),
            array(
                "name"  => __('Every 48 hours'),
                "value" => 60 * 60 * 48,
            ),
            array(
                "name"  => __('Every Week'),
                "value" => 60 * 60 * 24 * 7,
            ),
        )
    ) );

    return;

}

function msp_settings_callback($args) {

    $value = get_option( $args["id"] );

    if("dropdown" == $args["type"]) {

        var_dump($value);
        ?>
        <select name="<?php echo $args["id"]; ?>">
            <?php
                foreach ($args["values"] as $option) {
                    echo '<option value="' . $option["value"] . '" ';
                    checked( $value, $option["value"], $echo = true );
                    echo '>' . $option["name"] . '</option>';
                }
            ?>
        </select>
        <?php

    }

}
```

Comment: have you checked options table in db?

Comment: sorry i see now your reply on other answer

Comment: did you see your value sent to the server? Firebug it in "Net" tab, search for POST options.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go my friend:

```
add_filter( 'admin_init' , 'register_fields' );

function register_fields() 
{
    register_setting( 'general', 'msp_duration', 'esc_attr' );
    add_settings_field( 'msp_duration', __('Cache Duration') ,'fields_html', 'general' );
}

function fields_html() 
{
    $value = get_option( 'msp_duration' );
    $fields = array(
        array(
            "name"  => __('Every 6 hours'),
            "value" => 60 * 60 * 6,
        ),
        array(
            "name"  => __('Every 12 hours'),
            "value" => 60 * 60 * 12,
        ),
        array(
            "name"  => __('Every 24 hours'),
            "value" => 60 * 60 * 24,
        ),
        array(
            "name"  => __('Every 48 hours'),
            "value" => 60 * 60 * 48,
        ),
        array(
            "name"  => __('Every Week'),
            "value" => 60 * 60 * 24 * 7,
        ),
    );

    $output = '<select name="msp_duration">';

        foreach( $fields as $option ) 
        {
            $output .= '<option value="'. $option['value'] .'" '. selected( $option['value'], $value, false ) .'>';
                $output .= $option["name"];
            $output .= '</option>';
        }

    $output .= '</select>';

    echo $output;
}
```

Use the value with: `get_option( 'msp_duration' );`

Comment: thanks so much, never realized that the register_setting actually have to go with 'general'. Silly me

Answer (score 1):

Instead of [checked](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/checked), you should use [selected](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/selected) function

So your msp_settings_callback will look like this

```
function msp_settings_callback($args) {

    $value = get_option( $args["id"] );

    if("dropdown" == $args["type"]) {

        var_dump($value);
        ?>
        <select name="<?php echo $args["id"]; ?>">
            <?php
                foreach ($args["values"] as $option) {
                    echo '<option value="' . $option["value"] . '" ';
                    selected( $value, $option["value"]);
                    echo '>' . $option["name"] . '</option>';
                }
            ?>
        </select>
        <?php

    }

}
```

Comment: My problem is that I don't see any value saved into the DB. I can change the selected np, but this doesn't solve what I have at hand.

Comment: As Pontus pointed out main issue is with first argument of register_settings which should be 'general'